# Use xls, csv or other type of file to make a float array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, excel

Hi all, I'm *very* new at the whole programming thing, but I really like it. Sorry if I do not have enough details

So pretty much, I have excel files that have columns with numbers ( I can't post a picture because I don't have 10 reputations yet.

I've been searching for a couple days and I haven't really found an answer to this. I was wondering if there is a way that I could either create multiple arrays from the file - I know we can't make matrices like matlab - that have the numbers in each column, i.e.

```
float numbers[] =  {1.3, 1.2, 4.2};
```

Or create the excel file with numbers (the iWork version of excel), and import the numbers file into the xcode project and from there create the arrays

The issue I have is that there's around a thousand numbers so copying it one by one is extremely time consuming

sorry if this is confusing, please let me know if there's anything else I should add as information

Comment: Where do you have difficulty?  Creating a float array?  Reading a file?  Shortening time in reading thousands of observations?  I don't really know what you real question is.

Comment: @BlueTomato Thanks for the reply, I don't know how to create the array with all the numbers in it from the file. I also don't know how to read the file to extract the numbers

Comment: Your choices are basically CSV (comma-separated value), XML, and JSON.  If the data is coming from Excel then CSV makes the most sense, since Excel will generate that.  (And you can actually get away with opening the CSV or JSON file in a text editor and copy/pasting the data directly into an Objective-C array init statement, if you wish.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two easy ways to do this, even if you are a beginner.

Open MS Excel, input your values, save excel document as .CSV file.
Then grab an objective-c CSV converter like this one [here in github](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) and you are done.

The second way, you could declare an array of numbers (in example, 'float matrix[5][5];') and use it however you see fit.

I've done both of my suggestions in seperate projects and both work very well. I used the first method for a 15 page excel document that I needed to use in my app, the second method I used in another app that I needed to constantly change the contents of the 2d array. 
Once you declare the 'float matrix[5][5]' this is a 5x5 matrix (a.k.a. table) you can use it however you want. You could have the first array be the column and the second array be the row.

Comment: So once I download the file, how do I add a path to the file using xcode?

Comment: Just drag the CSV file to your a folder in your xcode project. I created a folder named 'Resources' (or it might already have been there) or I created a new folder in my xcode project called 'CSVFiles' You can literally drag and drop from the desktop to your folder in xcode.

Comment: KChockey: There are other CSV parsers out there that are easier to use than the one I mentioned. I looked for about 30 minutes, before I found one that I liked and was easy to use. I ended up modifying the parser code to do some custom behavior that I wanted it to do. So, if that CSV parser is not easy to understand there are more than a few on github.

Comment: Of course, CSV is so blazingly simple that one can write their own parser.  Basically it's just a call to `componentsSeparatedByString:`.

Comment: @Hot Licks, its not so simple when you need to handle all sorts of characters, such as spaces with special characters, and special characters such as "/", but if its just float values, then I would agree with you.

Comment: I love how people down vote on stackoverflow without giving a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You mean generate objective-C source from a .csv file? One way to do this would be to use a scripting language like Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @numbers = ();
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    push @numbers, $_;
}

my $numbers = join(', ', @numbers);
print qq(float numbers[] = {$numbers};\n);
```

This assumes that your .csv file (say foo.csv) has numbers in the first column and nothing else. If the file contains:

```
1.5
2.5
18842984
-4
```

And you pipe it to the script (foo.pl in this example):

```
cat foo.csv | perl foo.pl
```

It will output this:

```
float numbers[] = {1.5, 2.5, 18842984, -4};
```

Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure what the code means, but I will try. Where do I copy paste the pearl? and where do I run the "cat foo.csv | perl foo.pl"?

Comment: @KChockey - Perl is a scripting language built in on Unix systems and Mac OS. If you're on Windows, you'll probably need to install it, but it's free. The script and the .csv are both text files. You would type the command at a command line in a directory containing both files, and it will output the result. The example I gave will work on Linux or OSX; it says "output the contents of foo.csv to the foo.pl Perl script".

Comment: Thank you, but what ConfusedDeer said worked better for my case. However I will try this another time, thank you!

Comment: @slinberg The poster is asking how to import an excel sheet into his/her iOS project and this answer suggests a scripting language like Perl. I've heard great things about Perl, but there are much easier and (and MHO better) ways to accomplish the poster's request than creating a Perl script.